# how to handle this syntax error in django project

Tags: django, cloud, editing, linode

I have transferred my Django project onto Linode server already. The project was developed in VS, within anaconda (base) environment on my Mac.

After I downloaded it onto the Linode server when activating it, it gave me too many dependencies (not all needed it seemed). One of them prevented me from completing the process.

So, I sudo installed (in venv) needed packages (within the project’s virtual environment), for example:

```
certifi,
chardet,
Django…,
```

After creating ’static’ in the `settings.py`, on the linode server, I tried to collect static :

```
~$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

BUT I am getting this Error message:

```
/home/..../django/users/models.py", line 16
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong here? How can I fix this error?

Comment: f-strings are new in python 3.6, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.7.4; U checked that already. When I implement older version of formatting, I get an error that the .db module cannot be found. 
      The preproduction version worked fine, only when I connected with Linode, suddenly my local/original copy started throwing an error.

Comment: Unless, I should have created a separate virtual environment to start with. My Mac came with Py2.7... My project is using an Anaconda terminal which is set up as a default on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your python version. f strings are a fairly new feature, introduced with python 3.6. It's likely that you run an older version.

Comment: I am using 3.7.4; U checked that already. When I implement older version of formatting, I get an error that the .db module cannot be found. The preproduction version worked fine, only when I connected with Linode, suddenly my local/original copy started throwing an error. Prior to that, I was able to run a local server and my blog app was working fine. Thx